# Como pegar um valor dentro de um array com PP

Tags: php, array, api

Tenho uma API com algumas informações e quero pegar o Gênero: **Samba/Pagode**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 46484422
    [title] => Raça Negra e Amigos II (Ao Vivo)
    [upc] => 7891430177379
    [link] => https://www.deezer.com/album/46484422
    [share] => https://www.deezer.com/album/46484422?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=album-46484422&utm_term=0_1529271972&utm_medium=web
    [cover] => https://api.deezer.com/album/46484422/image
    [cover_small] => https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/45f27e183464715a67145b985dcbbd82/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [cover_medium] => https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/45f27e183464715a67145b985dcbbd82/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [cover_big] => https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/45f27e183464715a67145b985dcbbd82/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [cover_xl] => https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/45f27e183464715a67145b985dcbbd82/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [genre_id] => 79
    [genres] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 79
                            [name] => Samba/Pagode
                            [picture] => https://api.deezer.com/genre/79/image
                            [type] => genre
                        )

                )

        )

    [label] => Som Livre
```

Meu Código:

```
<?php
  $api = "https://api.deezer.com/album/46484422";
  $url = file_get_contents("$api");
  $json = json_decode($url, true); //This will convert it to an array
  $titulo = $json['title'];
  $capa1000x1000 = $json['cover_xl'];
  $musicas = $json['tracks'];
  $genero = $json['genres'];
?>

<?php echo $genero ?>
```

Porém, queria escrever o nome do Gênero, mas da esse erro:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in \api.php on line 29 Array

Comment: `$var->genres->data[0]->name` acho que é isso.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é um array, e pode haver mais que um género, não queres ter um ciclo para apanhar todos os géneros?

Se quiseres só o primeiro, seria só `$json['genres']['data'][0]['name']`, mas, caso uma destas chaves, `genres`, `data` não esteja definida, vai dar erro, até mesmo se `data` estiver vazio, porque estás sempre a tentar aceder ao primeiro.

**EDIT**

Exemplo do ciclo com HTML. No local na página onde queres apresentar os generos, podes por algo deste genero. Nao precisa ser um `<ol>`, pode ser qualquer outro elemento html que depois tens de usar CSS para dar estilos.

```
// ... html anterior que está na pagina ...

<ol>
<?php foreach ($json['genres']['data'] as $genero): ?>
    <li><?php echo $genero ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

// ... resto do html
```

Comment: E como fazer quado não tiver um gênero ficar em branco ?

Comment: Podes usar o `isset`. Por exemplo, `$genero = isset($json['genres']['data'][0]['name']) ? $json['genres']['data'][0]['name'] : "";`

Comment: E se tiver + de um Gênero, como posso listar todos eles ?

Comment: Um ciclo. Exemplo, `foreach ($json['genres']['data'] as $genero) { echo $genero['name']; }`

Comment: Testei esse ciclo, tem como eu colocar um 01. 02. 03. ates, e um abaixo do outro, ou seja um em cada linha ?

Comment: Adicionei uma edicao a resposta. Mas se estás a fazer html, é só colocares o html que precisas no ciclo para formatar o gênero conforme necessário.